# How to configure SSH Server - Password doesn't work when remotely connecting

Tags: ssh, remote-login

There seem to be many related posts, but nothing specifically addressing the following:

I configure SSH server, and I have been struggling with connecting to my SSH server remotely; It keeps prompting for the user's password and I never "successfully" enter it (It doesn't have any special character conflicts).

I recall that testing this on my localhost before leaving home I had the same issue. I entered the user password when prompted, but it was always denied.

Eventually I will setup keys, but wanted to try this first.

I tried running in verbose to see the issue, but I am pretty new to this interface and couldn't determine a problem.

What could cause the issue with a password denied when I only have one password for that user and it is correct?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the 'root' user?  Or a different user?  Are you sure the password you have is the correct password set for the user on the remote server?

Comment: please look at /etc/ssh/sshd_config may be PasswordAuthentication ia set to no ?

Comment: @ Thomas Ward: different user

Comment: @ einsh10: set to yes

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the user and start from scratch recreating it with the root user using:

First to delete

```
userdel username
```

Then to recreate

```
adduser username
```

is going to ask you to set the Password, then the User Information, that should leave you with a home, bin and ssh directories.

then you probably want to add it to the sudo group since you intend on using it remotely for SSH access, so go:

```
usermod -aG sudo username
```

that should leave you with a functional user you can sudo with and log into the server locally or remotely via ssh.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ DevilYan: I didn't want to delete  the user but isntead I created a new user, ran keygen, added to sudo group and same issue.